# How to write into json file without overriding in Java

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a method which store data to json file using ObjectMapper.Its fine.But When i try to add new data it clears previous data.Is their anyway to write without clear file.

```
 public String addnews(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Story story, 
       ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
        try{  
               String phyPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
               String filepath = phyPath + "resources/" + "data.json";
               File file = new File(filepath);
               if (!file.exists()) {
                   System.out.println("pai nai");
                   file.createNewFile();
               }
         mapper.writeValue(file, story);
         mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString( story);
         System.out.println("Done");
         } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          return "result";
       }
  Also how can i get back all those data
```

Comment: commons-io provides such a functionality: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io and it's the easiest way to do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.nio.file.Files` library, for example:

```
// Create JSON
final String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(story);

// Content is appended (due to StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
Files.write(new File(filepath).toPath(), Arrays.asList(json), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: How can store data as Json object like this [ {
  "storyTitle" : "test",
  "storyBody" : "sdzfdsaf",
  "storyAuthor" : "asdfasdf"
}
{
  "storyTitle" : "testasdfadsf",
  "storyBody" : "sdzfdsafasdfadsf",
  "storyAuthor" : "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
}] your ans create data without []

Comment: you need to add this manually, because it's not a standard JSON format

Comment: then how can i get back all those data